# How often should we read Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

I only look at meta.* once every couple of months. And then I see questions, answers and comments referencing "decisions" that were apparently made or changed weeks ago. I put that in quotes because I have no idea if these "decisions" were made by anyone with authority to decide anything.

I've been here a long time and have 23k rep but now I'm scared (Well, not really. Mildly concerned I suppose.) to use it for anything. If I do, I am sure to be doing something "wrong" by closing or deleting something.

It isn't that I want to be a part of the decisions. It's that I hardly know what the rules and guidelines **are** anymore. No one seems to bother writing them down, only mysterious references to month old Meta questions.

And yet I have no desire to read meta every morning.

Comment: I don't understand the question(?). If you want to be a part of the decision making process and/or helping others who have questions about how to use the site then you should visit often. If not...don't. It's up to you.

Comment: If you want to have influence over how the community is run (which 50% of people will ignore 'cause they don't know/have no rep etc.) then read meta far more regularly. I think it's worth it because I'm interested, others don't.

Comment: P.S., I want more people to be more interested and engaged in meta... The more opinions we have the better (and more representative) the site will be.

Comment: Read Meta every second of every day for the rest of your life. If Stack Overflow is crack, then Meta is 100% pure grade-A Colombian snow. Some people find Meta to be way more interesting than the questions they find over on the main site.

Comment: Shouldn't we open a meta.meta.stackoverflow.com section for this?

Comment: If you're interested in the badge, once a day for a hundred days consecutively.  If you're interested in the discussions, well...get in on a few of them and you'll find yourself here often enough. ;)

Comment: Meta: not even once.

Comment: Every time you can't resist the question title.

Comment: I think we're ready for [pata](http://www.pataphor.com/whatisapataphor.html).

Comment: @Cupcake Never thought about it this way, but Meta becoming more interesting (actually main site becoming overwhelmed with crap) is sad, but true...

Comment: I just look at the 'hot meta posts' box. ;) Anyway, I think most discussions here will solve themselves perfectly without my help.

Comment: @codeMagic: It isn't that I want to be a part of the decisions. Its that it seems I hardly know what the rules ARE anymore. No one seems to bother writing them down, only mysterious references to month old Meta questions.

Comment: @ZanLynx yeah, I can definitely see that as a problem. I kind of agree, there's no index of all important updates to rules and guidelines and stuff like that, you kind of just need to search for them. There are FAQ questions, but those are for *very old* stuff, none of the new stuff. There's no weekly or monthly newsletter updates either, at least since the split from [meta.se]. I guess maybe we could [set up a community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543/163250) for this sort of thing, just like they do over at Meta SE.

Comment: I would like to point out, however, that all major decisions are always widely publicized, both through the community bulletin, and also through the Stack Exchange blog and podcasts...so those already provide a certain degree of updates. Do you find those to be insufficient?

Comment: @ZanLynx: Rule 1: Questions and answers should be worth the read.  Rule 2: Don't be a dick.  Pretty much everything else follows from those, so if you're following them both, you're ok.  :)  Here, we mostly just chart that big grey area where the two overlap.

Comment: So you want the Meta Reader's Digest condensed version?

Comment: Meta is just a place for people to talk about SO. There's really no point to this site - there's significantly less respect for peoples' questions, posters make incorrect assumptions about the rules being wildly different here from other sites, and the mods back them up. Think of it like an AOL chatroom - nothing important happens here, but it's a place to get your word out if you want to do so.

Comment: @jberculo The meta site for meta.stackoverflow.com is meta.stackoverflow.com. Sources: First: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta Second: [meta-tag:meta]

Answer (score 15):

For someone like yourself I think the answer to your question is right in front of you, but you may have missed it. Keep an eye on the *Hot Meta Picks* box which is available from the main questions page on Stack Overflow.

[image]

Or using some of the [search tips from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you could craft your very own search URL that returns just the questions you are interested in viewing. For example this URL:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[feature-request]%20[discussion]%20-[support]%20is%3aquestion%20score%3a-2..%20closed%3a0%20duplicate%3a0

returns only questions that are:

- tagged as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
- are not tagged with [support](/questions/tagged/support)
- are not highly down voted (this one takes questions that are -2 or higher)
- are not closed
- are not marked as duplicate
- sorts the results by newest first

Comment: The funny thing is, I got to this question from that.

Comment: @justcool393 Since you pointed that out I had to go and replace the image - couldn't resist the self reference.

Comment: I usually glance at that box too and will occasionally click on something (like this one!) if it looks interesting. I'm not a huge meta follower either and usually find out about decisions when I notice that the reasons for closing have changed *yet again*

Comment: 1. having trouble deciphering your image, lack of freehand circles, etc. 2. I don't recommend this. In all honesty, the questions in this list are questions that are already solved and top answers highly voted. If you did want to say something, it's almost too late. If you want to be involved on meta and actually make a difference, you have to level up your hipster skills and answer questions before they're cool.

Comment: I swear, Mouseover Popup Image Viewer shows the [weirdest (sexiest?) of things](http://i.imgur.com/jsyCo.png).

Comment: Oh wait... We have recursion here! Oh wait...

Answer (score 6):

First place to look for *authoritative* guidance is not Meta but [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Second place is, again, not Meta, but moderator actions and advice.

In a perfect world, one wouldn't ever need Meta in addition to above. But world is imperfect and sometimes, you may find out that something is wrong or unclear. That's the case when Meta is *really* necessary - you go there to clarify things and get help.

---

Other than above, I believe that for your activities at Stack Overflow, references to Meta can be treated the same way how you treat references to SO (main site) in your programming activities.

- Say, you enter programming question in web search and it suggests you some SO post. - Similarly, you do something at SO and someone refers you to some meta post.
- You "have a right" to choose whether to ignore or explore SO reference suggested by web search. - Similarly, it's up to you to choose whether to ignore or follow and investigate suggested meta reference.
- Etc...

In particular, you can just blindly follow what you read at meta reference given to you. - This would be similar to blindly copying code from main site answer into your project.

It may work great, but if it fails, it's going to be all your fault for not checking and not studying things deeper.

Comment: "Second place is ... moderator actions and advice." How is this advice supposed to be received, if not through Meta? Annotations of rejected flags are terse and templated. And most flags don't go to moderators anyway. If it comes to the user receiving moderator messages, that means they probably should have read Meta...

Comment: @900sit-upsaday the question should be not "how" but "how often". Moderators are _human exception handlers_, they are expected to intervene rarely, that's by design. Post notices, mod messages, closures and deletions, locks, mod comments (in my experience they tend to use **bold** to indicate when commenting with mod hat on), stuff like that. Regular user doesn't see this frequently (and _shouldn't_ - site is designed to run mostly by community not by mods), but when they see it, _that_ is the "second place"

Answer (score 6):

[According to Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/):

> Meta-work becomes a reflex, a habit, an addiction, and ultimately a
>   replacement for real productive work. It's something I think everyone
>   should watch out for, whatever walk of life or career you happen to
>   have. In fact, I've come up with a zingy little catch phrase to help
>   people remind themselves, and their coworkers, how toxic this stuff
>   can be -- **meta is murder.**
>
> [image]

Comment: Friends don't let friends do Meta.

Comment: @Cupcake I'm not sure if there's another way to center an image in the editor here, but using `&nbsp;` just feels dirty and wrong...

Comment: Sometimes people are [forced to use sub-optimal solutions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25835/163250) `:P`