# What does "Meta police" mean?

Tags: discussion, meta, terminology

Earlier today, I found a [mention of Meta police in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268077/why-arent-moderation-tools-given-to-people-with-a-history-of-good-moderation#comment74343_268077) under [Why aren't moderation tools given to people with a history of good moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268077/2157640)

> Allowing those who don't have "skin in the game" to moderate has its own problems. We already have complaints about *"Meta police"*...

Tried to search the term both here on MSO and on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but found only old mentions of CW police. What does this term mean? Has it something to do with users moderating the site without participating in Q&A itself?

Comment: *"Has it something to do with users moderating the site without participating in Q&A itself?"* <-- that. Whether or not that is an actual thing though is not all that clear. It seems to be often used (in various forms) by users who are somehow dissatisfied with actions taken on their posts or on posts they like.

Comment: take a look at [MSE post pointing out the phenomenon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124531/165773): _'Another half to this problem is Lounge<C++>. Not all of them and not all the time, but do a search of their room for the term "meta police"...'_ There is also funny discussion in the comments to that post

Comment: Here's another take on the term, by yours truly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124455/33213

Comment: Meta resistance never gives up never surrenders

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Guessing right that Meta resistance is the group that gave rise to the term Meta police and is concentrated around Lounge<C++> chat room?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, it's a bit difficult to quantify, but I'll give it a try.

The "Meta police" is a term generally used to describe users who don't actively contribute to the site content, but who, in the minds of many, are there only to moderate and, in some cases, "destroy," other people's posts.

It's a term that's loosely used to refer to people who strictly enforce the rules and regulations that Stack Exchange puts in place (for good reason), and it has a negative connotation because it's usually used in a sense where one is in disagreement with said rules. The feelings also carry through because it is thought that these users who are more active on Meta than they are on the main site do not know what it feels like to have their question closed/deleted and therefore are more likely to do that to others.

It's also used to imply that people with moderation abilities/tendencies have too much power and that they use it incorrectly (this may be exaggerated by the ["Meta effect"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/258672)).

If you see it, the best thing to do is disregard both its mention and the person who mentioned it because chances are, they're just mad about some action taken on one of their posts (or a post that they were involved in). If they are angry about an action that they feel is incorrect, well...they can bring it up on Meta!

**Related**

- [Are we abusing our delete votes on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267969/are-we-abusing-our-delete-votes-on-meta)
- [Stop mob-downvoting users on the main site for their actions there and their opinions on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268171/stop-mob-downvoting-users-on-the-main-site-when-they-get-attention-on-meta)
- [How often should we read Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267138/how-often-should-we-read-meta)
- [Meta-meta: why is meta full of close-warriors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257918/meta-meta-why-is-meta-full-of-close-warriors)

Comment: I wish to note that the quoted comment (mine) was not using the term directly, but referring to  exactly the usage you describe.

Comment: Worth noting that [since the split](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), participation on MSO from active SO users is way, way up - I'm hoping this eventually leads to less of a perceived divide between the folks running the site and the folks *talking about* running the site.

Comment: AstroCB @Shog9 is probably right expecting divide perception to weaken. Its current prominence is very likely a heritage of MSE where voice of SO top users was only one of the many. Since the split, MSO looks like more and more like dominated by top tier SO users and it's getting increasingly harder to believe that _this meta_ runs by users who "don't actively contribute to the site content". Almost half of [top meta page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) is already occupied by users having 20K+ at SO and it's probably just the beginning of the rise

Comment: @Shog9 That's great, but frankly, I think one of the most amazing things about this model is the control that SE gives the community over the model in the first place. The "perceived divide" is very prominent for reasons I'm not entirely sure of: what other company allows you to post bug reports, feature requests, support requests, and host discussions about the site/company in the public eye and allows those postings to actually decide the direction of its development? How much more openness could you ask for? Why is there even a perceived divide at all?

Comment: @gnat That's good, but then they'll just find [something else to complain about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that).

Comment: I see... "elitist police", damn it, are we really getting at this? :) Hopefully it's only because this meta is very young, at more mature per-site metas I've seen there's typically too much disagreement between top users to allow clamping them with single label

Comment: @Shog9 are we sure this is attributed to the split and not to the 4 constant links to meta from the main site? (I agree it's very positive by the way)

Comment: The links that every other site had for years but we couldn't enable on SO until breaking off MSE? Yeah, those are probably a big help, @benjamin

Comment: @AstroCB so you're saying "If you see someone express dissatisfaction with Meta, the best thing you can do is to ignore it entirely". And you wonder why people are dissatisfied with Meta? I have to say, your clear "them vs us" attitude explains the term "meta police" much, much better than I could have hoped to do.

Comment: @Shog9 what about the divide between "the folks running or talking about running the site" and those who talk about neither and just contribute on SO? That's the divide I'm worried about. The divide between Meta and SE staff? I can't say I've ever been worried about that.

Comment: @jalf Exactly. If you want to be a part of the decision-making process, come here and voice your opinion. The community will make its decision and express its opinion via voting: you may be [downvoted, insulted, or even mob-downvoted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268132/3366929), but you will **never** be ignored. That's why this site exists. There is no "them vs. us" attitude: if they want to be "us," all they have to do is click the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ and `Meta Stack Overflow`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @jalf The same logic applies from my comment above, but you may want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267138/how-often-should-we-read-meta) and possibly [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268240/what-does-meta-police-mean/268244#comment75437_268244).

Comment: When I talk about "the folks running the site", I'm talking about the folks contributing to it, @jalf.

Comment: @Shog9 oh, I see. :)

Comment: How is my "mob downvoting" question supposed to be related to this? For that matter, why is my "delete vote abuse" question related as well?

Comment: @Cupcake I was speculating on whether mob-downvoting exaggerates the thought that Meta is some kind of exclusive "club" that works together to target certain users. The delete vote one was a bit of a stretch because it applies to Meta rather than the main site, but I think it still describes a common mentality here that may be angering people.

Comment: @AstroCB my delete vote question was with regards to posts *on Meta*, not posts on the main site itself. What about the mob downvoting?

Comment: @Cupcake The term "related" is used loosely, but I think all of the topics discussed in those posts relate to this because they deal with the way that Meta users control site activity.

Comment: "If you see it, the best thing to do is disregard both its mention and the person who mentioned it because chances are, they're just mad about some action taken on one of their posts" ... and that is exactly what we'd expect the meta police to do.

Answer (score 22):

It's an analogue to the notions of such frustrating, high-and-mighty individuals as the *grammar police*, the *clothing police*, the *noise levels police*, the *`<insert anything here>` police* who have placed upon themselves the responsibility and authority to judge, control and/or otherwise laud over their topic of choice.

> - This beer is delicious.
> - That beer is terrible. Why are you drinking that beer? I don't think you should drink that beer.
> - Who are you, the *beer police*? I can drink whatever I want.

The meta police are annoying, pedantic bastards who spend their whole life moaning on meta about someone not following the rules to the highest degree, often without really bothering to actually contribute to SO in the way that it was intended. They're spoiling for a fight, or they want to feel powerful, or they want to cause trouble, or whatever it is.

Comment: You nailed it - "without really bothering to actually contribute to SO in the way that it was intended."

Comment: I normally try to ignore meta as much as possible but +1 to this answer 1 million times.

Answer (score 7):

> Has it something to do with users moderating the site without participating in Q&A itself?

Yeah, pretty much. Meta has a somewhat varied history. It's a bit similar to the age old problem that the people who seek power are the last ones you want to actually *give* power to.

Meta is where you go to discuss how the site should function, how it should be moderated, how it should be improved on. Some people just vent their grievances there, and some try to "leave their mark" on the site by getting "their" rules or policies accepted on Meta. And some people hang on Meta much, much more than they're on SO.

Sometimes this works out well, sometimes not so much. In the past, the Meta community has been on crusades to delete and close *a lot* of content on SO, which sparked a lot of outrage among those who put time and effort into all that content.

The "meta police" is a negative term for someone who strives to police SO and tell people what they can and cannot do, and forcibly remove or edit others' content, rather than contributing content themselves. Much like a real-world police force, it describes people who see their *primary* purpose as enforcing the rules and keeping control.

The underlying issue that some people spend most of their time sharing programming knowledge on SO (paying no attention to how the site is governed via Meta), while others spend most of their time on Meta, paying very little attention to actually asking and answering questions) has previously given rise to some big fights, and can give the impression that Meta is "out of touch" sometimes, and leads to terms like "the meta police" and other unflattering terms.

It's also why I virtually never check Meta these days. It feels fundamentally alien to me as a SO user. It is full of people who want to police and control and close and delete and *discourage* contributions to SO, and every time I visit Meta I get into big arguments about that. So I try not to visit Meta any more. It's easier to just stay out of it, even if I disagree with the direction it's taking SO.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the "power" available to folks on meta is the power of persuasion - you don't exactly get any extra privileges on the main site for writing stuff here, and those who spend *too much* time here can end up lacking the privileges necessary to actually *implement* anything being talked about. One of the nicer side-effects of the meta split was that folks' rep here now reflects their rep on SO - so when you see someone with 1.5K talking about how stuff should be deleted, you know they're full of it...

Comment: Sure, that's true. I'm not sure I would agree that it is *just* a matter of persuasion (there are a lot of ways to influence a crowd, without resorting to plain old persuasion), but true, *formally*, people here have no special power. They're just able to meet and influence each others and coordinate their actions.

Comment: Which we were doing in external forums, chatrooms, and on SO itself prior to meta, @jalf - hence the reason for meta's creation, so that these discussions wouldn't be hidden away where other interested parties could not easily find them.

Comment: @Shog9 Yep, I know. I was around back then as well. ;) I'm not saying it was a mistake to create Meta (although sometimes I do wonder if it might have been). It's interesting though, in the early days I thought creating Meta was the best idea ever, and that creating chat was a completely idiotic move. Today, I use chat, but I find Meta to be a largely toxic place.

Comment: I feel the same way, but with the tools switched. Days when I have a productive discussion in chat are pretty few and far between - difference in styles, I suppose.

Answer (score -16):

It isn't difficult to understand at all.

The meta police are the people who come to edit your post 3 seconds after you've made it, without contributing or answering. They'll often leave a snide comment after doing so. Users find it annoying to get notifications about their question that have nothing to do with getting an answer and in some cases even indicate that someone has degraded or derailed their question.

Sorry to say it, but the person asking this question actually sounds just like one of those people; you're literally panicking because you've been called a name by a frustrated coder and don't know what it means, and you come to get reassurance from your buddies that it's just the stupid users not understanding your perfect set of rules for degrading and derailing questions. (Especially if those questions ask something you can't look up in a manual or on another site.)

Comment: Someone editing your post so that others can understand it, or posting comments that will help you clarify what you're actually asking for is someone who is contributing **far** more effectively to you getting help than someone who's blindly taking a stab at answering an unanswerable question.

Comment: How does someone clarifying and otherwise improving your question, or concisely but politely prompting you for all the parts you forgot to include, **not** contribute to getting you the answer you want?

Comment: Someone coming and adding formatting to my post is not contributing, sorry. This is the whole point - we are here for answers, not to contribute to some artwork stitched together from your favourite questions.

Comment: PS 5 downvotes in 12 minutes - this is more meta policing. I'm not surprised that people disagree with my opinion or don't like my tone, but can't you see the effect that this has when answers take days but the bitching starts seconds after any post?

Comment: _"Someone coming and adding formatting to my post is not contributing, sorry"_ Actually, that's contributing a lot for your benefit. If your question lacks formatting, that makes it harder to read _and less likely to stay open/get answers._ So the people editing your questions are helping you get better answers faster. To you, it may not seem like much. To them, it's giving your question more attention (your question gets bumped in the 'active' tab) and, hopefully, better attention.

Comment: Please see [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to explain why editing is important to this site. Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository for programming information, and editing posts to make them clearer or easier to read helps future readers to understand the information you have to share.

Comment: @Kendra and hichris123, yes editing is important. What will you edit when all the people who ANSWER questions and have INFORMATION to share are gone? Ask yourself: is it strange that we don't care about snide comments being made on posts but we do care what font parts of the post are in?

Comment: Derf, if you find a comment to be rude or offensive, you can flag it. And if the comment is rude or offensive _please_ flag it. Rude remarks are inappropriate here. Though if the person is just pointing out something you need to add to your question to get answers, then consider what they're saying before dismissing it. As to your first line... I'm not quite sure I understand what you are getting at and how that connects at all with people trying to assist you.

Comment: If you dislike an edit made to your post, rollback.

Comment: I can rollback... if I have sufficient reputation. And want to spend the rest of my life fighting back and forth between the original and the edits. Oh wait, only a certain type of person would do that. Someone with more time to spend making themselves feel good than programming. Wonder what we could call that type of person?

Comment: One last comment @Kendra - is someone who removes "thanks" off the end of posts helping? REALLY? Now picture someone who sits at their computer refreshing the list of topics every five seconds and trying to be the first one to do that ON EVERY POST. Would you call them a valued contributor? Would you feel comfortable being a new user with 5 reputation being told by someone with a million repturation that that's "not the way we do things around here"? Is that the first impression we want to give people? That someone who's *apparently* answered 100,000 questions is displeased with them?

Comment: @DerfSkren If that's the only thing in the post they're removing, I'd question it. A lot of times, posts from newer users have more problems than just that: Formatting, grammar, etc. If the user has more than 2k rep, they're not getting anything out of doing that, so it's not an abuse of the system or anything. There's even a topic in the help center about having things like "thanks" in your post.