# Can we unlock an offtopic question, that doesn't seem to provide historical value, so we can vote on deleting it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, vote-to-delete, historical-lock

[Best tools for creating website wireframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363/best-tools-for-creating-website-wireframes)

It is:

- Asking for a tool request
- POB (Primarily Opinion Based)
- Doesn't seem offer any historical significance

It's asking about wireframe tools from 9 years ago, it has been locked for 6 years, so the latest answers are not up to date. There's been much progress in software and ides since then, I'm questioning it's usefulness.

Does this question offer historical significance, if so, how? or
Can we unlock this question, so we can vote on deleting it?

**UPDATE:**

The question has been unlocked and deleted.

Comment: Doesn't the lock mean that people can't agree on deletion?

Comment: we'd have to delete all the duplicates first

Comment: @Stijn my understanding was it had historical significance for the site, ergo value

Comment: I've always interpreted it as a pretty wording for "some people think it contains useful info, some don't, so lets compromise with a lock".

Comment: @Stijn if that is so, then I have misunderstood it :/

Comment: It was asked a long time ago of course, so it is very likely that today there wouldn't be so much disagreement. If memory serves it has happened not too long ago that a really old question was unlocked to be able to get delete voted into question heaven.

Comment: @Gimby exactly my point. The only way to do it, is to ask here.

Comment: It was locked immediately after it was closed, so we should ask the moderator why that action took place, and if the reason is still valid today. (It hasn't been deleted at any point of time, just closed and locked)

Comment: @Braiam yes I was wondering about that. Not sure how to ping said mod

Comment: @Braiam You don't really need to ask Robert why it was locked (the reason is right in the historical lock message), merely determine if we *now* think that the post (still) has *significant* value.  If not, a mod can unlock/delete it.

Comment: @Servy why are you repeating what I said?

Comment: @Braiam I said that we don't need to do half of what you said should be done.

Comment: @Servy so using "because it's historical significant" is enough reason to lock a question that "why it's historical significant?" isn't a valid question? Interesting.

Comment: @Braiam No, I just said that the banner explains what "historically significant" is, and when it should be used.  You don't need to ask Robert why he locked it.  He felt that the question, at the time, was highly useful and merited keeping around.  You don't really need to know any more than that to determine if you think that the question is useful *now* and if we should decide to keep it around *now*.

Comment: @Servy why is this discussion useful? I don't find it very productive.

Comment: Those who don't know the history are doomed to repeat it.  Google "stackoverflow repocalypse", one of the more interesting podcasts.  If not, you'll at least find out what Shog9's dog sounds like.

Comment: <Calls the Meta Police> "To serve and delete!"

Comment: @RobertColumbia what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Yvette https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268240/what-does-meta-police-mean

Comment: @RobertColumbia ah, thanks :)

Comment: You’re right: it doesn’t seem to offer enough value to merit a lock, so, unlocked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Makoto may be right that the question and its answers are useful, but "useful" is not the fundamental benchmark of whether to keep content. If someone posted a guide to the New York City subway system, would you let it stay on the grounds that it is useful? Stack Overflow was never intended to be a receptacle of miscellaneous factoids. If you want that, I recommend Wikipedia.

Comment: "Useful" is *literally* one of the words used in the tooltip when you up or downvote content.

Comment: @Makoto: no contradiction. You can upvote an off-topic posting, if you think, it’s useful. That’s not necessarily preventing deletion (though it might make it harder).

Comment: @Makoto Let's try to be a little bit context-aware, here. It seems clear that the intended meaning is, useful *in the context of Stack Overflow* i.e. its mission and purpose.

Comment: "factoids" "Wikipedia" Wikipedians everywhere are triggered