# Hide questions with negative scores from front page?

Tags: feature-request, questions, voting, front-page

#### What I want

Obviously question quality is one of the most important issues that faces SO (Stack Overflow). I'm perfectly happy reading a new question and <del>down</del>voting on it, but I think I would have a better experience (i.e. spend more time reading interesting questions, producing quality answers, and enjoying myself more) if I weren't exposed to questions that other users found subpar, *even* at the risk of ignoring other salvageable questions.

In other words: I'm willing to do the work of sorting out very fresh questions. But once a question has any weight against it, I'd rather not concern myself with it. Just like there's probably power users who only hang out on the "featured" page, I'd like to not look at the worst of the worst when I visit SO.

To be clear I want this to be a custom default view when I visit SO (i.e., opt-in). I think that will have a bigger impact on my workflow (i.e. what I do when I'm really lazy and check SO without thinking) than having to dig around for this.

#### Why I think this works

In my experience, -1's sometimes survive (I wind up there when I miss key info on a question that I thought was obvious or something), but I don't think I've ever seen a -2 of reasonable quality. In any case I think once you have one downvote you deserve *less* attention. Perhaps even weighting these questions so a -1 has a 50% chance of being hid from a visitor, etc. would both be fairer to users like me, and fair to the asker's prospects of having the question tended to at all (still enough people will have a chance to upvote).

There's other improvements - for instance edits can behind the scenes count as a positive vote until the next vote, etc. but the basic idea is tenable.

Comment: Yes please! The current threshold is -4, and 99% of the questions between -3 to -1 are crap. (Heck, 90% of the stuff at >= 0 are also crap)

Comment: I disagree. I often enjoy editing bad questions to make them more suitable for SO. I don't want to have to dig around for the setting to show these questions any more than you want to do the opposite.

Comment: @anthropomorphic clarified what I mean by default. i.e. not default global; customizable default.

Comment: Though it's probably fairly easy for someone with userscript experience to make a script for this.

Comment: @djechlin I think negative vote count = lesser chance of being seen works so long as questions get a significant bump every time they are edited, so that a question that gets improved will have a chance at earning upvotes.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I noted this in second paragraph under "Why I think this works."

Comment: @djechlin sorry, I must have skimmed over that bit.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I still sort of stand by my point. If _so_ many users like me use this hypothetical feature that questions can't get attention, then we clearly had a big problem with how much we were coddling bad questions and scaring away answerers. Which is so much worse than scaring away askers, by the way.

Comment: @Mysticial [Done](http://stackapps.com/questions/4846/hide-negatively-voted-posts-from-the-front-page).

Answer (score 3):

I've written [this simple userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4846/hide-negatively-voted-posts-from-the-front-page) to hide posts with a score of less than 0 from the front page of all SE sites.

This is a permanent solution that I would prefer you to use temporarily: I wouldn't count on SE raising the score threshold anytime soon, but personally, I don't want them to. With this script, if one drive-by downvoter happens to drop a vote on a question, that question is immediately **gone** from your front page, halting any efforts you might have given to fix it up with editing/comments.

So, use this wisely, and try to turn it off every once in a while.

(One little piece of irony: once you turn this on, this post will not be visible on the Meta.SO front page.)

Comment: This is good. People seem to be wary of my part of the answer, where if *everyone* installs this script and neglects the -1 questions, then maybe we had a bigger problem than those questions being neglected. IOW, I do so much on this site, why is tending to -1 questions a required responsibility.

Comment: @djechlin That's why userscripts are great: they let you customize your SE experience a bit without forcing stuff on other users.

Comment: Fair (I will continue my argument about the theory in my main question). Anyway, I upvoted, thanks.

Comment: @djechlin My pleasure. (Really: I enjoy writing [these little fixes](http://stackapps.com/users/25923/astrocb?tab=questions) inspired by Meta posts. It's interesting.)

Comment: Oh nice! I should try this at some point. But yes, I too do not believe that I should be forced to see the things that I don't want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are not aware of it, there is already an algorithm under discussion to ensure that low quality questions get less eyeball time, and conversely high quality questions get more - check out [*Podcast #59 – The Decline and Fall of Stack Overflow*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/)

Having said that, if you remove a negatively weighted question too soon by default, you also remove any chance of someone editing it into shape. Sure, a lot of the negatively weighted questions are bad and should be sent to the scrap heap, but a small (but significant) percentage can be saved. I think a better approach would be to speed up the removal of unsalvageable questions rather than outright removal of all "bad" questions.

Additionally you can craft up your own search query so that only questions with a minimum vote and above are shown - have a look at the example I [give here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267267/109702).

Comment: Would I just bookmark stackoverflow.com/?mySearchQuery for that solution?

Comment: @djechlin Yep, that is one way to do it, possibly have it on your bookmark bar if you have your browser set up to show it.