# What are the meta-questions that every user should read?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm a fairly new user in this amazing community and am very interested in understanding how things work around here.

Whereas there 7.6k meta questions. Which would be the most relevant for understanding the evolution of the community over time?

A timeline would be an excellent way of presentation.

Comment: You can anchor your timeline with [hats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats) and work backwards from that. Read: Don't take anything too seriously.

Comment: The evolution of the community over time is a *very broad* topic that would be covered by thousands of questions both here and on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) which was previously MSO. I would recommend that as you encounter more specific issues, you search for the questions related to those specific issues.

Comment: If you are talking about meta itself, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work

Comment: [SE changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange "Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange"), if one is interested to learn about _evolution_

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [How often should we read Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267138/how-often-should-we-read-meta)

Answer (score 7):

Every user should read the FAQ:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq