# How can we distinguish official policies and procedures from opinions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

When policy and procedure questions are asked, how can we determine what is official policy and procedure versus what is someone's opinion?

Comment: I suppose it depends on who answers. If there's a diamond, and a lot of upvotes, and not a team of other diamonds commenting in disagreement, it is probably _sort of_ official.  But there are also some people in the community who aren't diamond mods or SE developers who have amassed or ascertained impossibly deep knowledge of how the network works -- from hanging out on meta all day.

Comment: Part of the beauty of Stack Overflow is that lots of the "official" policies are actually just positions that have evolved out of community consensus. Certain things are codified in the help center as fully official, but as with anything else here, upvotes/downvotes indicate the degree of community agreement with any given post.

Comment: @sphanley - I don't mean to seem argumentative, but with millions of members, I've never seen a question or answer amass enough votes to be considered representative of a community or a sampling of the community. You could even say 1000's of members (say those with more than 500 reps).

Comment: Closely related question from Meta.SE: [How is consensus determined on meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550)

Comment: Does the software enforce it?  then it's official policy.  otherwise, it's opinion

Comment: @SamIam That's not strictly true.  There are official policies that aren't enforced in code.  (And also things enforced in code that aren't official policy.)

Comment: "First place to look for _authoritative_ guidance is not Meta but [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Second place is, again, not Meta..." ([How often should we read Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267268/839601))

Comment: @jww - see George Stocker's answer for a better statement of my point. Whether you see it as a "complete representation" of the community, a lot of the site's standards and moderation policies come out of the discussions of however many people choose to participate in Meta.

Comment: If this is related to our recent exchange about a "Not an Answer" flag, and you would like me to respond in that context, please let me know.

Comment: Newbies on SO do not really know every rule of conduct here because not everything is collected at one central place. But (un)fortunately people will tell you if you make something wrong and quite often one also gets links to relevant discussions.

Answer (score 29):

The closest we get to hard rules are the items listed in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (particularly the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)) and the [legal terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Everything else is a convention that has been openly debated at some point on Meta.SO or Meta.SE. These conventions can change, such as the what kind of content is acceptable in an answer. Arguments are made for and against ideas, and most people accept that the more popular suggestions are what they'll follow as an informal policy.

We never get anywhere near a significant portion of the ~3.5 million registered users to participate in these discussions, but the people who care the most about site policy tend to have their say or vote. Again, little of this is considered binding, but the community does tend to gather around specific points of view.

As much as we programmers would like to have hard and fast rules for everything, that's not how the world works. For every convention, there are exceptions, and we all have to make our own decisions about what actions we think benefit the site.

Answer (score 14):

Answers on meta (at any given time) reflect the views of the people who visit meta.

Sometimes these answers are codified as official positions; you'll note these when someone says "This is how it is." (and they happen to be an SE Inc. employee).

That doesn't happen very often, if at all.

What you're more likely to hear (from a moderator) is "This is how I moderate. This is why I moderate this way."  That's not an official SE Inc., position, just a statement of how and why the moderator does what they do.

If a community member posts an answer and it receives a lot of upvotes, it is also not official SE Inc. position.  It is a barometer of how the people on Meta feel at any given time, and should be treated as such.

At the end of the day, the organic workings of community moderation and the elected moderators' actions determine what 'official' policy is; and that is something that is hard to pin down, because much like everything: it depends.

Comment: So is this the official policy about such answers?

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that faq posts _usually_ carry more weight.

Answer (score 11):

In general, you can't. Not from posts on Meta anyway. Even answers written by moderators and devs cannot be guaranteed to be anything more than opinion, *unless otherwise stated in the post*.

Comment: Just because someone says that their post is 100% official policy doesn't necessarily mean that it actually is.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, it can be outdated. Otherwise, an official spokesman stating that they are acting as official spokesman *in that instance* is as good as it gets.

Comment: It would be presumptuous to demand that every single question on Meta need be answered by *an official spokesman* -- they may have better things to do. And on hotly debated issues, when noticed, they may choose to let Democracy Rule and wait for the dust to settle.